# DCE MRI time axis

Tags: dicom

What is the time sample interval in DCE MRI data. That means, I have the signal intensities over time (30 time samples) of one pixel and I want to know what is the sample interval.

Is it the TR or should I read the DICOM information from each dicom image and compute the time? If I should compute it from the DICOM information, is it the "Content Time" tag that gives me the information? I am working in Matlab.

Comment: I may be out on a limb here, but on [this](http://www.slicer.org/slicerWiki/index.php/Documentation/4.1/Modules/MultiVolumeImporter) wiki page the *Trigger Time (0018,1060)* tag is claimed to identify the temporal resolution of the individual frames in an DCE-MRI image?

Comment: There is no value on "Trigger Time" in my data. As I can see the only tag that changes on the different images is "Content Time".
Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Which MR SOP class is used for this data?

Comment: SOPClassUID: '1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4' 
is this what you are asking?

Comment: So this is the legacy MR format, not multiframe data.

Comment: These are Dynamic Contrast Enhanced MRI data that means 3D volumes over time (4D data). Could you please give me some documentation? The time tags that change over pictures are "Acquisition Time" and "Image (Content) Time".

Comment: Content Time actually seems like a reasonable choice.  It is defined as, "The time the image pixel data creation started," and is a type 2C attribute that is required for images that are temporally related.  I have some reservation about whether or not vendors have properly interpreted the meaning of the attribute, though.  Does your data include a Temporal Resolution (0020, 0110) attribute?

Comment: There is no such attribute in the data set I am processing. Finally I think I arranged properly the dcm files using the "Content (Image) Time". I am curious whether this algorithm is going to work in other data sets (e.g. from another MRI modality).
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the image instance number(0020,0013) and slice location(0020,1041) to determine the image time points. For example, go through the images for one slice location, there will be N(time points) images, then you sort those images with instance number, you'll get the ordered image series with time points.